# Node.js memory leak, despite constant Heap + RSS sizes

Tags: node.js

According to my server monitoring, my memory usage is creeping up over time:

[image]

After ~4 weeks of uptime, it ends up causing problems / crashing (which makes sense, given that I'm on EC2 with m1.large instances => 8GB RAM, and RAM seems to be increasing at about 1.5 GB / week).

If I restart my node.js app, the memory usage resets.
Yet... I'm keeping track of my memory usage via `process.memoryUsage()`, and even after ~1 week, I'm seeing

```
{"rss":"693 Mb","heapTotal":"120 Mb","heapUsed":"79 Mb"}
```

What am I missing? Clearly the leak is in node, yet the process seems to not be aware of it...

Comment: Are you using node's cluster module? Perhaps the reported memory usage belongs to one of the child processes. Also, did you verify what process uses all that memory using ps/top? What version of node.js are you using?

Comment: Can't answer without actual code. But you may try https://nodetime.com/ to dig for memory leak.

You may restart clusters with high rss size. Which is very dirty solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [node-memwatch](https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch) module, which helps with leak detection and heap diffing in Node.

Heap diff would look similar to:

```
{
  "before": { "nodes": 11625, "size_bytes": 1869904, "size": "1.78 mb" },
  "after":  { "nodes": 21435, "size_bytes": 2119136, "size": "2.02 mb" },
  "change": { "size_bytes": 249232, "size": "243.39 kb", "freed_nodes": 197,
    "allocated_nodes": 10007,
    "details": [
      { "what": "String",
        "size_bytes": -2120,  "size": "-2.07 kb",  "+": 3,    "-": 62
      },
      { "what": "Array",
        "size_bytes": 66687,  "size": "65.13 kb",  "+": 4,    "-": 78
      },
      { "what": "LeakingClass",
        "size_bytes": 239952, "size": "234.33 kb", "+": 9998, "-": 0
      }
    ]
  }
```